# In pandas Dataframe, how do you insert rows, then copy/paste the cell values to the inserted rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns that looks like:

```
Filename   ID      No   class  stage
A1         A1000   1     a      1
A2         A1000   1     a      1
B1         A1000   1     a      1
B2         A1000   1     a      1
A3         A1001   2     b      1
A4         A1001   2     b      1
B3         A1001   2     b      1
B4         A1001   2     b      1
```

As you can see, rows are in multiples of four (for each ID). I would like to do:
1) Insert two empty rows after each row
2) Copy and paste the rows to the inserted empty rows

The desired dataframe after above process should be:

```
Filename   ID      No   class  stage
A1         A1000   1     a      1
A1         A1000   1     a      1
A1         A1000   1     a      1
A2         A1000   1     a      1
A2         A1000   1     a      1
A2         A1000   1     a      1
```

and so forth. I am currently testing out some posts on stackoverflow but I keep getting stuck. Is there a way to perform the above process? Thank you!

Comment: Also would like to thank the other person who answered my question with np.tile. It also worked the same but the post was removed before I could reply to it.

Comment: Dont use accepted answer, because all values are converted to strings. Better is `df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)]`

Comment: check it by `print (pd.DataFrame(pd.np.repeat(df.values, 3, axis=0), columns=df.columns).dtypes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution using `Index.repeat`:

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)]
```

Comment: Better like accepted answer, comment under question.

Comment: Agreed, that’s a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

With `np.repeat` (no need to `reshape` in this case as opposed to suggested `np.tile` solution):

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.np.repeat(df.values, 3, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
```